# PHP, MySQL - find the position of a product in a bid for specific product

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **bid** table:

```
id | product_id | price | quantity | user_id | created_at
```

I need to select all the bids for the selected user and show the bid position in comparison for the same product. This is an example of result I need (I need to order it by created_at).

```
Product 2 - 22$ - 100p - Position 3
Product 2 - 33$ - 100p - Position 1
Product 3 - 2$  - 100p - Position 7
Product 2 - 30$ - 100p - Position 2
Product 4 - 69$ - 100p - Position 4....
```

As you see results are not linear since the user will get bids for different products and random time. 
Is this possible to do with a single query?

Comment: **Post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Add a sample input data set that fits your sample output.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: `<strike>` *"I need to order it by date_created"* - I think you meant *"by created_at"*, right?`</strike>` You should also post your schema/values for this. I don't know what you mean by "position".

Comment: *"I need to order it by created_at"* - didn't an `ORDER BY created_at` not work? could it be that simple? or does this go deeper?

Comment: *"so please bear with me"* - yeah we tried; where are you? oh never mind, I decided to leave the question. You've answers below, see those.

Comment: As per advice, I gonna delete this post and try to make it more clear, with examples.

Comment: It seems there is a contradiction in your statement. You actually don't want all bids from a selected user, you want all **products** on which a bid by the selected user exists. This amounts to "I want all bids from an arbitrary list of products (which happens to be all the bids from a user)". First find that list, then find all its bids. Much simpler to solve.

Comment: @sasha from your lack of response, I am starting to believe that maybe you question really was simply about ordering by created_at as stated by Fred. Could you clarify if really all you want is that or if I surmise the right thing?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - I am still working on this, and until I can formulate the question right (or solve the issue), I think it will be the best not to edit the question (since I am not allowed to delete it). 
That being said - this is not simple ordering by created_at. I need to sort data by created at and calculate the position of each product based on the price. 
Which means bids will be shown in chronological order, and after price, I need to show the position of the bid for that product. The issue is that user can have multiple products put for bid, and bids will come and random time.

Comment: @Sasha no problem, I just wish you would clarify if what you really want are only the bids from the specific user, or all the bids on a product **on which a user has a bid**. I believe I made some assumptions about that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT id, product_id, price, quantity, user_id, created_at
FROM bid
WHERE user_id = @user_id
ORDER BY product_id, created_at DESC
```

Comment: this will not have the bids from other people on the same product

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's because he specifically said he wanted them for a user:

"select all bids for the selected user "

Comment: You are taking it out of context. What they really said is "I need to select all bids for the selected user and show the bid position **in comparison for the same product.**" (emphasis mine). Unless what they really mean is compare all the bids a single user made with all the other bids that same user made, that means all the bids from other people. If it's not clear at this point, there is no question if really all they want are the bids from a single user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need:

- retrieve data for 1 **user**
- group it by **product**
- get the **user**'s bid *row* **position** per product *ordered by* **creation date**

I found `ROW_NUMBER()` that you could try if supported.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at) AS Position,
         id, product_id, price, quantity, user_id, created_at
    FROM bid
    GROUP BY product_id
) subquery
WHERE subquery.user_id = 1
```

**BUT** I think my query is wrong, it's an attempt. Edit my answer if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Using the order by select statement

```
Select * FROM database WHERE product_id = your_product ORDER by PRICE
```

you can then use ASC or DSC on end to put in different orders

Comment: this is for a single product, not all the products a user has bid on.

Comment: Oh IC what you mean

Statement = "Select * FROM database WHERE user_id = '" .SESSION['current_user'] . '" ORDER by PRICE"
While()
{
Select * FROM database WHERE product_id = '". $request['productid'] . "' ORDER by PRICE
}